# angular.element().hide() versus ngIf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, directive, jqlite

Angular gives access to some jquery functions [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

I'm just wondering if there is any difference in performance between .hide() and using the ngIf directive?

*Added clarification that came from comments*

I understand the difference between ngIf and ngShow, but I'm wondering about the performant differences between using the ng directives versus calling angular.element() and chaining it with .hide()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `.hide()` method is equivalent to `.css( "display", "none" )`, while `ng-if` remove the element from the dom. This is the major difference.

jqlite  `.hide()` acts the same way as `ng-show` / `ng-hide` directives

> The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display
>   style to none (using an !important flag).

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: so ngHide uses .hide()? I understand the difference in the DOM - I'm more curious about the difference between the directive and the jquery throwbacks. (it is all still very helpful, though)

Comment: i've edited my answer. As reported in the doc ng-hide style the element with display: none !important, but actually i think it uses the jqlite implementation rather than jquery, probably .css( "display", "none" ). https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 3):

`hide/show` would not remove the element from the dom but would just add `display:none` property where as `ng-if` would `remove` the element completely from the `dom`.

If your UI has a lot of elements, you can use ng-if to instantiate the relevant ones which would save a lot of resources. As your view does not need to create all the ones and then apply `display:none` property to one which should not be shown in `view`.

If you are going to `remove` and `show` an element very often from your view, `hiding` it instead of `removing` could improve `performance`.